# Automapper: change map behavior based on presence of custom attribute

Tags: .net, automapper, custom-attributes

Is it possible to have AutoMapper look for an attribute on the source property?  I want AutoMapper to change how it maps the properties when those properties have a specific attribute set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box that allows you to do this. You will need to use reflection to read attributes for a given property and based on it's value adapt the mapping.